# How to use socket file to access server if SSH Agent forwarding is enabled

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys, ssh-agent, bastion

I have bastion host. I connect to the bastion host using username/password. And I have private key for destination Server. Flow:

```
Local Machine -> Bastion -> Destination
```

I know that It's dangerous to use **Agent forwarding** because someone may read my **socket file** (If they have root access to bastion host)  while my **session is open** and access the destination server - so I should use **ProxyCommand!**

Now I'm just **testing**  how to access destination server **without private key** if I have **access to the bastion server** - how dangerous is Agent forwarding.

```
Host bast
     Hostname X.X.X.X
     ForwardAgent yes
     User bastion
```

**Questions:**

- I've seen that there is information about the active agent to the following location in the bastion server:  Ex:  **/tmp/ssh-{name}/agent.[PID]**. I have root access but I can't read this file. I think only **process Id is enough** for this file, **is not it?**
- if agent forwarding is enabled where can I find the socket file? I try to find at **/proc/pid/fd/** location, where I saw several socket files.
- how can I access to the destination server using the socket file? (How to access destination server via the ssh using socket file)

It tried to find socket files here:

```
 /proc/PID/fd/
```

And then just try this command for each socket 3,4,5,9,11:

```
ssh -p 2072  -o "ProxyCommand socat - UNIX-CLIENT:/proc/PID/fd/11" app@[DESTINATION_HOST_URL]
```

Result:

```
2018/08/26 01:53:31 socat[13552] E connect(5, AF=1 "/proc/13510/fd/11", 19): Connection refused
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

[image]

Log:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec socat - UNIX-CLIENT:/proc/14003/fd/11
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
2018/08/26 03:10:17 socat[14073] E connect(5, AF=1 "/proc/14003/fd/11", 19): Connection refused
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: Hi, can you please answer my question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/958222/bastion-server-use-tcp-forwarding-vs-placing-private-key-on-server

Comment: I read answers too. Agent forwarding is okay, but I would use proxy command instead. Do you need additional examples how to setup proxy command? - usage, how to upload/download files etc?

Comment: I wrote the answer about how to hack agent forwarding. :) and examples how to setup using proxy command :) I hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just changed value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` then in `ssh-add -l` I had a key loaded.

To sum up:
It's dangerous to use agent forwarding because if you have root access to the bastion host - you can steal key whole session is open. You just need to to change `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and that's it!